# Returning a dynamically allocated copy a const char *s without using any other functions from the standard library except malloc() and free()

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write this function called strdup where strdup() returns a dynamically allocated copy of s, or NULL on failure. s is a C string. The
returned copy must also be a valid C string using the minimal amount of storage required for the copy.

I am not allowed to use any other functions (e.g., from the standard library or otherwise assumed) except malloc() and free(). I may assume that if I returned the address of the dynamically allocated storage, it is the responsibility of the user to free that storage.

Here is what I have came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *s)
{
  char *copy;
  unsigned length = 0; //best to use here, given the cirumstance

  while(s[length] != '\0')
  {
    ++length;
  }
  ++length;

  copy = malloc(sizeof(*copy) * length); //better to use the size of copy

  if(copy == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  char *copy_orig = copy; //save a copy of 'copy', but why?

  while(*s) //testing for a null char, not a null pointer (while(s))
  {
    *copy++ = *s++; //seg fault
  }
  *copy = '\0';

  return copy_orig;//why?
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char *s = "Hello, I am a String";
  printf("%s\n", s);

  printf("%s", strdup(s));
}
```

The code compiles but seg faults at run-time, I am not sure why.

Comment: You seem to be missing the clearly-noted `malloc` usage in this function. That space has to come from *somewhere*. I wish I had given such hints 30 years ago when I was going through this.

Comment: Crap. You're right.

Comment: I added it but I still run into the same problem.

Comment: Jacob, Curious: who or what text suggested casting  the return value from  `malloc()`?

Comment: `while(s)
  {
    *copy = *s; //seg fault
  }` This is an infinite loop if s is not null.

Comment: I found the suggestion for casting malloc() here: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/alloc/intro/ Their reasoning was that malloc returns a generic pointer.

Comment: Also, sizeof(char) is defined to be one, so that code should be eliminated.

Comment: How should I copy s into copy? Not sure how to write a loop to do that under the conditions given.

Comment: @Jacob, this page seems to be more than 20 years old. It is not particularly good and misses improvements of the C standard that have come in since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In while loop you not increment pointer. I rewrite it to copy without using pointers

```
char *strdups(const char *s1)
{
    int i;
    int lenth;
    char *p;

    lenth = 0;
    while (s1[lenth])
        lenth++;

    if ((p = malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenth + 1))) == NULL);
        return NULL;

    i = 0;
    while (s1[i])
    {
        p[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    p[i] = '\0';
    return p;
}
```

Also if you want to write it using pointers

```
char *strdups(const char *s1)
{
    int len;
    char *p;
    char *tmp;

    len = 0;
    while (s1[len])
        len++;

    if ((p = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    tmp = p;
    while (*tmp++ = *s1++);
    /* Empty Body */

    *tmp = '\0';
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Why? does it not the same? assign then increment?

Comment: No. With `p[i] = s1[i++];`, it is not defined if `p[i]` received the pre-incremented value of `i` or the post increment value.  Research _sequence points_.

Comment: Minor conceptual point: `sizeof(char) * lenth + 1` should be `sizeof(char) * (lenth + 1)`.  In this case `sizeof(char)`   makes no math difference.  Yet if code was ported to a wider character type like `wchar_t`, then the size should be multiplied by `lenth + 1` and not `lenth`.

Answer (score 0):

Various problems:

Allocation done before the string length was found.
Wrong iteration test when copying.  [@FredK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937398/returning-a-dynamically-allocated-copy-a-const-char-s-without-using-any-other-f/48937625#comment84881996_48937398).
Copy loop failed to increment pointers.

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
  char *copy;
  // `size_t` is the best type, yet given OP's limits, `unsigned` is a good next choice.
  // int length = 0;
  unsigned length = 0;

  // delete 
  // copy = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

  while(s[length] != '\0') {
    ++length;
  }
  ++length;

  // Move allocation here
  // Cast not needed
  // Better to use the size of the de-referenced pointer than code the type
  //   This is easier to code right, review and maintain.
  copy = malloc(sizeof *copy * length);

  // A good touch includes a memory allocation check
  if (copy === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Save a copy of `copy`
  char *copy_orig = copy;

  // Need to test for a null character, not a null pointer
  // while(s) {
  while(*s) {
    *copy++ = *s++;  // Also need to increment the pointers.
  }
  *copy = '\0';

  return copy_orig;
}
```

---

If you like `do` loops

```
  while(s[length] != '\0')
  {
    ++length;
  }
  ++length;
```

can be replaced with

```
  do {
    ; 
  } while(s[length++]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting a seg fault.

Comment: not enough space allocated - need length+1 to account for the null terminator OOPS - just saw that it is actually included in computing length.

Comment: Still running into a seg fault. I see why you put in the incrementing of the pointers.

Comment: @Jacob Yes, code errantly returned the wrong pointer.  Post amended.

Comment: I've updated my code, you can see in the question. However, I am confused as for why we should save a copy of 'copy' and then return it without giving it any other values?

Comment: @Jacob  Note that after the `while(*s) {
    *copy++ = *s++;  
  }` `copy` points to the end of the _string_.  Instead of returning that _pointer_.  `strdup()` needs to return the original _pointer_ value allocated.  This was saved with `char *copy_orig = copy;`.  This assignment gave _pointer_ `copy_orig` a value.